# Multiple javascript animation of masks of a svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to animate the radius of the circle #mask-hole-2 with javascript. So that it animates the radius from 0 to 175px. But i dont know how to do this in a common way. I cant use css cause there seems to be another specification used on firefox for animating masks with css.

```
<svg width="400" height="300">
 <defs>
  <mask id="hole">
   <circle id="mask-hole-1" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="165" fill="white" />
   <rect id="mask-hole-3" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <circle id="mask-hole-2" cx="165" cy="156.5" r="145" />
  </mask>
 </defs>
 <image width="400" height="300"
   xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/"
   mask="url(#hole)"/>
</svg>
```

I want #mask-hole-1 to change its radius within 2 seconds from 0 to 175. After 2s #mask-hole-2 should change its radius from 0 to 175 also. 
Would be nice if the animation works smooth. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use SMIL: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html

Comment: unfortunately i dont know what you mean. could you please provide a snippet? the animation itself has to be triggered at a certain scroll position. it is important to mention that the js solution should work in firefox only cause in other browsers its already working

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/